# J1 grace period ends 3 days before I leave. How to proceed?

Tags: usa, j1-visas

I bought my ticket to go back to my country according to my DS2019 dates, which expired on Dec 20 (so my grace period would be until Jan 20), but later I received another DS2019 from my sponsor with a new expiration, this time on Dec 12 (grace period = Jan 12) but I leave on the 15th, 3 days after this new grace period ends. I tried to contact my sponsor but they won't answer and to change my ticket is too expensive at this point. If I leave 3 days after my grace period is over, will I have a problem with that? Will I be able to come back at another time? Besides the J1 visa I also have a tourism visa.

Comment: "will I have a problem with that?" A problem with *what*, exactly?

Comment: Just to clarify: your sponsor changed the ending date of your DS-2019 to an earlier date? Do you still have the old DS-2019 form? Does it still have the same SEVIS number?

Comment: yes, to an earlier date. I still have the old DS and both have the same SEVIS numer

Comment: user102008 with the fact that I am leaving 3 days after my grace period. In other words, if I decide later to apply for an employment visa or something, will I have more chances to be denied the visa? Even if I try to come back as a tourist, will that be compromised?

Comment: @Pedro: Nobody can predict whether you will get a visa in the future. It is entirely up to the whims of the visa officer. How a visa officer decides is completely subjective and there is no point to speculate; e.g. I could imagine that one visa officer treats how long you stay (legally or illegally) as having a bigger effect than whether you stayed illegally. Nobody knows. There is no legal barrier to you getting a visa.

Comment: and to return, even as a tourist? Is there a chance after I get here they will send me back from the airport?

Answer (score 1):

For any Visa related problems, you must feel free to contact "INS - Immegration and Naturalization Services" of US Govt.

I am sure they would understand that your intention can not be any violation in staying just 3 days more and they will allow you officially to extend it to 3 days. Better to get permission than to keep guessing how much will you damage your reputation as rule abiding visitor.

They do have fax numbers and you can keep a copy when you depart in case you have not received reply in-time.

Comment: Especially by showing the original form that shows that you made a good-faith effort to comply with the rules.

Comment: INS has not existed for more than a decade